# Default expire time for a cookie in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

What is the default expire time of a [cookie](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) in Rails (3.1.3)?

I have found documentation on how to set, how to retrieve, but I fail to see the default expire time.

Comment: Hey @hommer-smith, want to close the question?

Answer (score 14):

By default, cookies expire at the end of the session (meaning when the user closes their browser).